# Null checkboxes are not checked on load of SSRS report in browser. Why?

Tags: reporting-services

I have made a report in SSRS which has 6 date parameters which can be null so has null checkboxes attached with it.
I want that on opening the report the null checkboxes should be checked.
They are checked when I open the report in the report builder but when I open it in the browser then the checkboxes are not checked.

How can i make it possible to keep checkboxes checked at load of report, also in browser?

Comment: Which version of SSRS are you using? Do you have default values specified in the report server (`Manage` => `Parameters`)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check the parameters in your browser (I assume that you have sufficient privileges to the properties  of the report?)

Make sure `Has Default` is checked along with the `Null` settings

[image]

Comment: It worked.. I didnt knew it can be done from here... Thanks.. It helped a lot..!

Comment: Some might call it a feature ;-).  You can definitely set it in VS before deployment and the first time you deploy the report, the value should be set.   But subsequent deployments will ignore defaults set in VS  (hence the 'feature', which I've found often useful, sometimes painful).  If you want the default set every time you deploy, you have to remove the report on the server before deployment.