# Date parameter NULL checked in preview but not when run in browser

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have several date parameters in my SSRS report. I check "Allow null value" and "No default value".  When I preview the report in Visual Studio, the NULL checkbox next to the date is checked, just what I want.  However, when I run this same report in the browser, the NULL checkboxes are NOT checked.  If I specify a default value of (Null) I get the same exact results.

1. Why the different behaviors?
2. How do I force the NULL boxes to be checked no matter where the report runs?

Answer (score 2):

Did some more digging and found this answer that solved the problem.  Apparently the server is not smart enough and has to manually be set.

[Null checkboxes are not checked on load of SSRS report in browser. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31027825/null-checkboxes-are-not-checked-on-load-of-ssrs-report-in-browser-why)

Answer (score 1):

You must have to check parameters on report server and make sure **Has Default** is checked along with the **Null**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to set the Default value to NULL to make it work the way you expect.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but as I said, that does not work.  Actually it works correctly in VS but not in the browser.